# can't use usb with ubuntu server

Tags: boot, usb

this will sound stupid I know, but I deleted win8.1 of my laptop and installed ubuntu server instead of desktop, now the laptop is not seeing the usb, all 3 ports, I tried several boot disks and usb sticks to put a different OS on, reset the bois, but still the laptop is not seeing the usb, how can I fix this? I want to install ubuntu desktop or go back to win 8.1,

thanks

Comment: You can install `ubuntu-desktop` on your existing box without using a usb/thumb-drive. Your USB may have died, or be disabled in BIOS/UEFI which is a hardware matter.

Comment: how can I install without a usb?

Comment: I did reset the bois, but still can't read anything from usb, I know how to write few MS dos command, that's about it

Comment: 1a. Please tell us details about your computer: brand name and model number; 1b. If 'home-made' pliease tell us brand name and model number of your motherboard. This will help us help you. Also, please tell us how you created the USB boot drive (2a. which version of Ubuntu Server, 2b. which tool to make the USB drive bootable). Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` will add the Ubuntu Desktop to your existing system; it'll be GNOME if 18.04 LTS or later, or Unity if you're using 16.04 LTS

Comment: its an Acer aspire 5, I installed 18.4 LTS, server, I made a bootable dvd, I took the hd out now and put it in another computer to delete it

Comment: As far as I understand both Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop recognize the USB ports by default. You should not need any special action to see and use the USB ports. Why did you delete Windows? Did Windows recognize the USB ports? Is there reason to believe that the hardware is faulty? -- Maybe it will be easier to download an iso file with Ubuntu Desktop as suggested by @guiverc. You can try that live booted from DVD or if possible from USB (if the UEFI/BIOS system will allow it).

Comment: there is no reason to assume the usb is faulty as I used a usb DVD player to install ubuntu, the reason I deleted win, I have 3 computers, a Mac and 2 win, and I wanted to try ubuntu and maybe leave win, as it's very slow, so I picked my 5 years old laptop, I connected the hd to my desktop and booted the computer with an old copy of ubuntu, and deleted the hd and now installing a copy, will put it back in the laptop and see, I can access the bois, but the system is not reading from usb, it turns the DVD player on, but not booting from. it, I used few dvds that I'm sure they work,

Comment: I have no own experience of Acer and don't know details about this computer brand, but I am sure there are many people here at AskUbuntu, who have Acer computers and know. Let us hope an Acer user will read this and help you.

Comment: after erasing the hd and installing ubuntu 16.4 it booted the desktop, took it back to the laptop it didn't work, but I can use usb, installing fresh copy of 16.4 on the laptop now from usb, the server version just blocked my usb

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)